# What is the difference between the operator acting elementwise vs on the matrix using Numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, operators

[Numpy docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations) talks about the difference between the product operator and the matrix operator.

> Unlike in many matrix languages, the product operator * operates
> elementwise in NumPy arrays. The matrix product can be performed using
> the @ operator (in python >=3.5) or the dot

Question: What is the difference between the operator acting elementwise vs on the matrix?

How would it change the outcome?

Comment: right below the two sentences you quoted from the docs, there's an example that should answer your question.

Comment: And even without examples it should be obvious what element wise means, it means that one element from the matrix is multiplied with one element from the other. That is not how a regular matrix multiplication works which is why there a dedicated operators for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we've got two matrices:

```
a = [ p q ]
    [ r s ]

b = [ w x ]
    [ y z ]
```

Element-wise product means:

```
a * b = [ p*w  q*x ]
        [ r*y  s*z ]
```

Matrix product means:

```
a @ b = [ (p*w)+(q*y)  (p*x)+(q*z) ]
        [ (r*w)+(s*y)  (r*x)+(s*z) ]
```

When literature in math, machine learning etc talks about "matrix multiplication", this matrix product is what is meant.  Note that `a @ b` is not the same as `b @ a`.